# Open site through ShellExecute without losing focus on main window

Tags: c++, winapi, browser, hide, shellexecute

In my code I open site with

```
ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "http://google.pl", NULL, NULL, SW_MINIMIZE);
```

It is almost perfect but after browser initialize and open link , main game window lose focus and browser windows is now on top. 
I would like to open link in browser but game window should stay on top without minimizing etc.

Browser window should be opened but in the background.

I tried SW_SHOWNA , SW_HIDE , SW_MINIMIZE nothing works.

Comment: The `nShowCmd` parameter is a hint. The spawned process is not obligated to honor it. Per the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153.aspx): "If lpFile specifies a document file, the flag is simply passed to the associated application. It is up to the application to decide how to handle it. "